# Why do we weigh less in the morning?

Tags: metabolism, circadian-rhythms

At first I thought it may be related to physics.  You know, in one half of the day, the gravity changes, and the scale shows a different weight than the other.  Then at night, gravity intensifies, and you become slightly heavier.

But I'm a bit skeptical about that. Is that true?  That it's somehow related to gravitational fields?

Comment: Gravity changes over the course of the day? Why should it?

Comment: Gravity (at a given location at a given height) doesn't change.  A simple google search would answer your question: respiration releases carbon and water, you sweat, releasing water, and you spent eight hours not eating to boot.  http://www.businessinsider.com/weight-morning-skinnier-2014-7

Comment: [_Veritasium: Are you lightest in the morning?_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lL2e0rWvjKI)

Comment: There is a related question: [_Physics SE: Are we slightly lighter during the day and slightly heavier at night, owing to the force of the Sun's gravity?_](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121775/41684), which _might_ be what you mean by "gravity changes", though **the commonly held misconception** of why you should loose weight during the night is due to digesting food and burning calories (and debunked in the answers below).

Answer (score 6):

[Veritasium](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHnyfMqiRRG1u-2MsSQLbXA) created [an excellent video just on this topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lL2e0rWvjKI), which I would recommend watching, but will summarize here.

A common misconception is that we lose weight when we digest food or burn calories. Keep in mind that that broken down food and those calories`*` aren't "going anywhere", so technically you shouldn't loose any mass (unless you get rid of the molecules by going to the restroom).

However, in the "informal" tests done by Derek Muller, **he lost about 250 grams each night**. Since during the night you sweat (which evaporates or gets absorbed into the sheets and blankets), he estimated that about **150 grams was lost through perspiration and breathing out water vapor**.

The more surprising loss of mass, was 0.012 grams of carbon lost with each breath when breathing in oxygen, and then breathing out carbon dioxide. Although this seems like a tiny loss, assuming you breathe in and out about 7,680 times each night, that tiny mass loss adds up to almost **100 grams of weight loss through breathing alone**.

I guess health magazines should start running articles like *"Top way to lose more weight? Researchers say breathe more!"*

Comment: `*` Technically _calorie_ is a unit of energy and not an item that can be "burned". What we mean when we use the word is the process of molecules being broken apart, which releases energy that can be used by the body; however, the pieces of the "broken up" molecules still weigh the same as the molecule as a whole, so we don't loose weight just from "burning calories".

Comment: It's not really so surprising. Carbon is converted to Carbon dioxide which is exhaled. A quick back-of-the envelope calculation shows this makes sense: 1kg of fat has about 38000kJ, that's a bit over 3 times the energy used in a day, so if we don't eat, we convert about 300g fat into CO2 in a day, or 100g during sleep (1/3 day).

Answer (score 5):

There is indeed a slight weight variation during the day. About 2 - 4 lbs (approx. 1 - 2 kg) [1, 2].

Some causes are:

- water loss *through respiration, perspiration or urination* [1].
- the relative long period without eating and drinking [2].
- metabolic processing of food and drinks during sleep.

References:

1. Cindy Banyai. http://www.livestrong.com/article/483853-how-much-can-weight-fluctuate-from-morning-to-night/
2. http://www.weightlossforall.com/weighing-less-morning.htm

Comment: Not eating or drinking and Metabolic processing does not change your weight/mass, that violates conservation of mass. The only thing that affects body mass are excrements (from urine, sweat, and faeces), respiration, and very small amount of debris from your skin/hair.

Comment: Mass can be converted into engergy. Setting something on fire does change the weight/mass of for instance your house, doesn't it? This is what your body does when you "burn" calories. You don't eat (add something), but your body stays 37 degrees -> the energy to keep it that temperature (even ignoring things like heartbeat and other processes like your brain) has to come from somewhere. Apart from that, the law of conseveration of mass deals with closed systems (also closed for energy!) which you body certainly isn't.

Comment: @Nanne Mass isn't "converted to energy", at least not in our human body (unless we go thermonuclear, which would be awesome, but just doesn't happen). What we do when we "burn" calories is break the chemical bonds between glucose(?) molecules; the breaking of these bonds releases the small amount of energy stored in them by the plants that spent that same amount of energy in order to produce those bonds. The combined mass of the "broken apart" molecules is still the same as the "complete" `C6H12O6` molecule.

Comment: (If a biologist or chemist could double-check my comment, I wasn't sure if it was glucose or sucrose that gets broken apart. Moreover, as I only have a basic understanding in the field, I may have other minor flaws in my comment)

Comment: @Nanne _Setting something on fire does change the weight/mass of for instance your house, doesn't it?_ > It doesn't; if you measure the increased weight of the air (the smoke particles in it) and the remaining ashes, there is no difference in weight. _Technically_ [there is a loss of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_energy#Mass-energy_relation), but it is unmeasurable by _any_ equipment you could buy at a store.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to gain weight, consume things. Thus after any period of time not consuming anything (i.e. sleeping) we must necessarily weigh <= what we weighted at the start of that time period. Add in respiration, and that becomes a strict inequality!